# Creating sequence number for set transactions

Tags: text-processing

I have a file which has different record_types. (positions 1-2 in the sample below; `1`,`2`,`1A`,`2A`,`3` etc..are the record_types)

File1:

```
1 xxxx uuuu dfffgg cvbd 
2 jjj oo dhjkkk ooo             
2 9555 schghf kllls                                         
1A chkds tddc ihg  
2A hkkseadc             
1 fdsff kljjgt uoohgf            
1A ghyytd gkddgg tusab sg;dadug tdskd              
1A gdjhjkh hdw ouiy axv kaksh ;ljqskl            
3 gdhd tfyw ;lk;k; joo     
1 gdhsgdhj uyutyu ljkgjg                        
2 hjkhclkshclk jhshcklj  dhkjdh                  
2A hjkdhfsh jj okop oipo
```

I want to generate a sequence number to make set transactions. For example, from record_type 1 till the next occurrence of record type 1 is considered as 1 transaction`

In the above file e.g: from 1 till 2A (1st 5 lines should be 1 transaction file) from next  1 till 3 (lines 6 till 9th line ) are 2nd transaction and next occurrence of 1 till 2A is 1 set of transaction etc..

I want to do this split accordingly. I used the below code to generate sequence and use it:

```
awk ' BEGIN {SEQ=0 } {if ( substr($0,1,2) == "1 " ) {SEQ++;} print $0SEQ }' file1 > file2
```

Now my file 2  looks like:
(The sequence numbers are getting added to the last digits of the line.)

```
1 xxxx uuuu dfffgg cvbd1                                                                                             
2 jjj oo dhjkkk ooo1                                                                                                   
2 9555 schghf kllls1                                                                                                 
1A chkds tddc ihg1                                                                                                     
2A hkkseadc1                                                                                                      
1 fdsff kljjgt uoohgf2                                                                               
1A ghyytd gkddgg tusab sg;dadug tdskd2                                                                    
1A gdjhjkh hdw ouiy axv kaksh ;ljqskl2                                                                            
3 gdhd tfyw ;lk;k; joo2                  
1 gdhsgdhj uyutyu ljkgjg3                  
2 hjkhclkshclk jhshcklj  dhkjdh3                    
2A hjkdhfsh jj okop oipo3
```

The sequence numbers are getting added to the last digits of the line.
That causes validation issues for me while passing values with fixed position length.
Is there any way to add the sequence number at the desired fixed position or at the beginning of the line rather than the end?

Is there any better way to do this grouping of set transactions?

```
awk ' BEGIN {SEQ=0 } {if ( substr($0,1,2) == "1 " ) {SEQ++;} print $0SEQ }' file1 > file2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increment the sequence number when you see a 1 in the first field. Then keep using that number to prefix the records until you see a 1 again in the first field. Rinse n repeat.

```
awk '
$1 == 1 {seq++}
{
  print seq $0
}
' file
```

Output:

```
11 xxxx uuuu dfffgg cvbd 
12 jjj oo dhjkkk ooo             
12 9555 schghf kllls                                         
11A chkds tddc ihg  
12A hkkseadc             
21 fdsff kljjgt uoohgf            
21A ghyytd gkddgg tusab sg;dadug tdskd              
21A gdjhjkh hdw ouiy axv kaksh ;ljqskl            
23 gdhd tfyw ;lk;k; joo     
31 gdhsgdhj uyutyu ljkgjg                        
32 hjkhclkshclk jhshcklj  dhkjdh                  
32A hjkdhfsh jj okop oipo
```

Comment: This works thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
awk ' BEGIN {SEQ=0 } {if ( substr($0,1,2) == "1 " ) {SEQ++;} printf "%10d%s\n",SEQ,$0 }' file1 > file2
```